# How to return a multidimensional Mat array from a function

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, mat

I want to return a cv::Mat object with a [w][h][c] dimensions, where w is width, h is height and c are channels or depth. But the compiler gives me an error.

This is my code:

```
cv::Mat three_channel_convolution(cv::Mat bgr_image, cv::Mat kernel)
{
   cv::Mat feature_map[3];
   cv::Mat bgr[3];

   cv::split(bgr_image, bgr);

   for (uchar i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      feature_map[i] = one_channel_convolution(bgr[i], kernel);
      std::string name_feature_map = "bgr_feature_map_" + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg";
      cv::imwrite(name_feature_map, feature_map[i]);
   }

return feature_map;
}
```

In this function I want to make a convolution with a filter (kernel) for each of the three channels in the image BGR. So the convolution function returns the result of the operation in one channel (A single 2D Mat [][]) and stores it in the feature_map Mat array. How can I return this Mat array?

Then in my main() function I call the function like this:

```
feature_map = three_channel_convolution(image, kernels[0]);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: you declared the method to return a `cv::Mat`

Comment: You are returning reference to the temporary object (temporary array). You can return `std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>` or `std::array<cv::Mat,3>`

Comment: You currently create three different `cv::Mat`s, because you `cv::split` the input image. You just need to `cv::merge` them again before returning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of the function `three_channel_convolution`  is `cv::Mat`, but you return `cv::Mat[3]`.

If you like to return a 3d Matrix you need to change the signature of the function to something like `std::array<cv::Mat, 3>`. Please keep in mind, that this might have some performance issues.

```
std::array<cv::Mat, 3> three_channel_convolution(cv::Mat bgr_image, cv::Mat kernel) {
   std::array<cv::Mat, 3> feature_map;
   std::array<cv::Mat, 3> bgr;

   cv::split(bgr_image, bgr);

   for (uchar i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      feature_map[i] = one_channel_convolution(bgr[i], kernel);
      std::string name_feature_map = "bgr_feature_map_" + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg";
      cv::imwrite(name_feature_map, feature_map[i]);
   }

    return feature_map;
}
```

Ps. Please report the exact error message in further posts.

Comment: The  "pointer" solution works. I understand that what Im doing is returning a pointer to where the mat array is stored. But can you explain please, what Im doing if I use std::array<cv::Mat, 3> in the returning value of the function?

Comment: An plain old array can not be used as a return value. You can do two things. First (old c style), you can return a pointer to the start of the array. This might be unsave and you have to take care of the memory. This also hold, if you give a pointer as an output argument to the function. Second, you can us a C++ container a return value. Since C++11 you will have the so called return value optimisation, which will make it quite fast and no unneeded copies will be created.

Comment: @PabloCano In that case you are returning a `std::array<cv::Mat, 3>`. `std::array` is an object just like `std::string` or `std::vector` or `cv::Mat` and you are returning one of those. It's the simple solution, much simpler than returning a pointer. The fundamental problem you are having is that regular arrays are not *first class objects* in C++ and there are some things that they cannot do (like being returned from a function). `std::array` is a way of filling that gaps that regular arrays have.

Comment: @jhon And once I have the returned object in a valid variable in the main funtion, Can I use the cv::Mat methods or atributes like it was a normal cv::Mat object?.